# How did simply visiting a site made my iPad unresponsive?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, virus

I went to this weird site for fun named

### (DO NOT VISIT THIS SITE UNLESS YOU HAVE A VIRTUAL MACHINE)

***virus4u dot com***

This site is extremely malicious. On a school computer, the audio screamed "Alert Alert! Virus detected!" Until I forced shut it down. On androids (LUCKY) they simply show you a scam "Win an iPhone X for only 1$"!

After I went on the malicious site on my iPad, it said that my iPad was **LOCKED** and I had to contact "Apple Thec Support". I am aware this is scam, but my iPad was freezing, plus when I tried closing the site, It would not close, and I also could not slide to power down my iPad.

After I forced shutdown my iPad (holding power + home), everything is now *normal*.

However, I am very puzzled. How the heck can a website make so I cannot slide to power off, and freeze my iPad, even after clicking home button!? I couldn't swipe or click. I need more explanation on this!

iPad Mini (iOS 9.3.5)

**This is not anything about a virus removal, also not sure if this should be here or on Information Security.**

Comment: What possessed you to even go to this site in the first place?

Comment: I honestly  don't know. But I'm curious on how these sites work in the background. Currently I am using this iPad and everything is as it used to be.

Comment: Imma test it out brb

Comment: Thanks for the link! I won 3 free iPhones and 2 Amazon gift cards! ;) Anyway, it's probably just a coincidence glitch. The site, like many others, redirect a bunch of times. It probably just redirected a bit too much causing a random glitch that probably wouldn't happen again.